# SQL Server 2012 deadlocks on update query

Tags: sql-server-2012, deadlock

We are getting deadlock on a very frequently used table with this query:

```
UPDATE ChatMessageReceiver With (RowLock) 
SET DeliveryDate = '05/31/2016 06:05:35',
    ReadDate = '05/31/2016 06:05:35', 
    ModifiedDate = '2016-05-31T06:06:30.4263992' 
WHERE 
    ChatMessageId = 'F19F4D1D-D2C9-401E-9999-264B8A4765C8' 
    AND ReceiverId = '73E6B553-ACAE-47C0-A0C9-29092F5722C8'
```

We have removed all the indexes (Including clustered index on the `ID` column) as we have applied row level locking and also the combination of `ReceiverId` and `ChatMessageId` is unique.

Why we are getting a deadlock?

Comment: Why did you remove all the indexes?

Comment: As due to index we are getting deadlock on inserts also but removing indexes help to atleast reduce that.